# Running a Python program from a C program using system()

Tags: python, c, execvp

I am tasked with creating a C program that writes a python program (which prints "hello world") and executes it.

I have completed the first part (writing the python program to a file) but when I try to execute the python program from C, nothing happens. I directly tested the created file and it has the expected input so I am likely doing something wrong when attempting to execute the python program.

I am attempting to use system() in order to execute the python program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
        FILE *pfile;
        pfile = fopen("execute.py", "w");
        fprintf(pfile, "print(\"hello world\")");
        int system(const char *command);
        system("python3 execute.py");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fclose(pfile);` before `system(...)`. I will use `popen()` or better yet `execl()` instead of `system()`. Also notice that you don't need this line: `int system(const char *command);`

Comment: Call *fclose(pfile);* or *fflush(pfile);* before the call to *system()*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest,

```
fclose(pfile);
```

fixes the issue

Comment: You have fixed the issue, but ... 1) You don't check the result of `fopen` and `system`. 2) You have tagged your question `execvp` and included `unistd.h`, why? Notice that you don't need any non standard library to run `system` (`stdlib.h` is enough).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I had originally used execv commands to try to complete my assignment before coming across system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).